# Numbers of combination of groups

Tags: probability, permutations, binomial-coefficients

I have 120 people and groups of 6 people and i want to know the probability that I am in the same group as a specific person (call him x)?
I’m little confused about the usage of the binomial and how to count the number of combination in which I am with this person.Thanks in advice

Comment: Well, put down concretely what you have in mind, and what is confusing you about your attempt.

Comment: For what its worth, you can completely avoid the usage of binomial coefficients for this problem if you wanted.  You will be in some group, it doesn't matter which... in some seat within the group, again it matters not which.  Without loss of generality, suppose it was the first group in the first seat.  Now, your friend $x$ will be in one of the other seats in one of the groups somewhere.  Five of which lead to him being in the same group as you.  All others, not.  Five good seats out of $119$ remaining seats...

Comment: Well, you have already been given the answer, but it would be educational to attempt it using binomial coefficients.